# Vertical icon bar with angular material

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to make a vertical icon toolbar. I want it to be on the right top side. It shall only occupy the width of the icon (24px and some padding).

I tried this

```
<div layout="column" layout-align="top end">
  <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="close">
    <md-icon md-font-icon="zmdi zmdi-close"></md-icon>
  </md-button>
  <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Favorite">
    <md-icon md-font-icon="fa fa-print"></md-icon>
  </md-button>
  <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="close">
    <md-icon md-font-icon="fa fa-print"></md-icon>
  </md-button>
</div>
```

Any smart way to achive this with angular material directives? Or must I do it manually with css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/pNjeBx)

I did the original for this example (which was on the left hand side) for another question which I can't find for the moment. I've answered again to help yourself and others.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" layout-fill layout="column">
  <md-content flex layout="row">
    <div flex>
      Your content
    </div>
    <div layout="column">
      <md-whiteframe id="vericalToolBar" class="md-whiteframe-8dp" layout="column" layout-align="start center" flex>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="More">
          <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/more_vert.svg"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Favorite">
          <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/favorite.svg"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <p id="toolBarTitle" class="md-title">My vertical toolbar</p>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Favorite">
          <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/cake.svg"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </md-whiteframe>
    </div>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#vericalToolBar {
  background-color: rgb(1,74,182);
  width: 40px;
}

#vericalToolBar md-icon {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.87);
}

#toolBarTitle {
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.87);
}
```

Comment: Could you add where content is placed next to the vertical icon bar? I tried it and the content ends up under the vertical icon bar.

Comment: Is this possible with the new angular material library mat-* ?